# Fancybox 3 full size image

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

Is it possible to disable "zoom in" function and get the full image size with Fancybox 3 gallery? And also enable horizontal and vertical scrollbars for a large images.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using `clickContent` option; 2) What? 3) Sorry, no

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue & fixed using "clickContent" option

ex.

$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
          clickContent: false,
});